# Unit testing a polymorphic association with fixtures in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need to unit test a promotions model where every campaign has a URL. There is a polymorphic association between promotions and reference_link. the reference link fixture:

```
reference_link:
  linkable: 
    fix_1 (PromoCode)
```

How do I convince rails that the promotions fixture does indeed have a URL belonging to it?

In promotions test helper:

```
test "should have a URL associated with the promo code" do
  promo_code = promo_codes(:fix_1)
  promo_code.reference_link.url = nil
  assert_not promo_code.valid?
  promo_code2 = promo_codes(:fix_2)
  assert promo_code2.valid?
end
```

promocode.rb

```
class PromoCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reward
  has_one :reference_link, as: :linkable, dependent: :destroy
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :code, presence: true
end
```

reference_link.rb

```
class ReferenceLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :linkable, polymorphic: true,touch: true

  validates :link_name, presence: true
  validates :link_url, presence: true 
  validates_format_of :link_url, :with => /\A#{URI::regexp(['http',    'https'])}\z/
  validates_length_of :link_url,:link_name, :maximum => 255  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you almost got it right. First, ensure the fixtures are correctly set:

```
# promo_codes.yml
promo_1:
  email: 'foobar@gmail.com'
  name: 'Foobar'

# reference_links.yml
reference_1:
  linkable: promo_1
  link_name: 'lorem'
  link_url: 'http://loremipsum.com'
```

The tests:

```
# promotion_test.rb
test "should have a URL associated with the promo code" do
  promo_code = promo_codes(:promo_1)

  assert_eq true, promo_code.reference_link.present?
end
```

Do not forget that file naming is an important part of convention that Rails use.